# I want to execute Stored Procedure and continue without waiting for the result. The failing or success of the Procedure execution doesn't matter

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I am calling a Procedure from the model file in Laravel . But I don't need to wait for the result. I want to continue with the rest of the code. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
 public function createTestTransaction($id, $stockid, $transactiontypeid, $userid)
{
    DB::update('exec usp_save_transactions ?,?,?,?',
        array(
            $id,                    
            $stockid,               
            $transactiontypeid,
            $userid                
        ) );
    
    $text = "rk";

    return $text;
}
```

In the above example, I need to get the $text despite the success of the procedure execution.

Comment: Short answer: hand it off to a background process (e.g. cron job which can see what tasks have been allocated to it by the front-end (perhaps in a DB table, or via a message queue) and execute them on a regular schedule.

Comment: What happens if an error occurs in the procedure?

Comment: The result would not be saved to the db and the user knows it from the transaction table in the frontend and would repeat the process.  But to continue is important.

Comment: @ADyson I think making it a cron job is the best way to go. Thank you.